# Unirgy uRapidflow, a Magento extension

Tags: magento

```
ACTIVITY,,,"Preparing data"
ERROR,,,"Warning: Illegal string offset 'field'  in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/example/includes/src/Unirgy_RapidFlow_Model_Mysql4_Catalog_Product_Abstract.php on line 364"
```

Hello good people,

As you can see from the above error, I cannot get Unirgy RapidFlow (a magento extenstion) to export my data. I'm using Magento EE on nginx, php-fpm, CentOS 6.3

It was working fine under Magento/Apache. Then I got assigned a project to move to nginx from Apache. All went well until I realised the RapidFlow extension in Magento had broken. It seems to complete the export with some warnings if I don't select any columns (fields). As soon as I select a column and run it, I get the error as above.

A little more data to help you find a solution:

-Working well with Apache

-Then I installed nginx and php-fpm

-I also did an update to CentOS using epel 6.8 and remi 6 repos

-MySQL, php and bunch of other stuff got updated.

-Current MySQL is v5.5.29

-Current php is v5.4.10

-Current nginx is 1.0.15 (Although I don't think this is the problem. Reverting back to Apache is giving me the same error.

-Current Magento Enterprise v1.12.0.2 (on both the production and development servers)

-After the update, RapidFlow threw a error about ioncube_loader_lin.5.3.so PHP module but I fixed that part when I installed the 5.4 module. Now the "illegal string offset" error appears.

There is some json thing v1.2.1 installed. I have a feeling it's something to do with json and MySQL.

All works well on the production server which has CentOS 6.3, MySQL v5.1.61, PHP 5.3.3 Json 1.2.1

Any help would be great. Pointing me in the right direction would also help a lot.

Many thanks.

PS. I'm trying to post a screenshot but this system won't let me as I lack the required reputation points

Comment: you should submit a support request to the good people at unirgy.com, they will be best able to help you

Comment: @JonathanDay LOL That's what I did about an hour ago :-) Once I get their response, I'll post the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

After much dilly dallying, they finally admitted to a bug in their code. A new release should fix it. Meanwhile, they suggested I turn off magento developer mode when I need to run Rapidflow, then turn it back on. It is one line to be commented in and out in index.php